# Terraform force destroy S3 bucket very slow

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

I am trying to delete S3 buckets with 1000s of objects. I am using `force_destroy` params to true to delete all the objects in bucket during tf destroy.

It takes really long time.

When I enabled `TF_LOG` to `DEBUG`, found it is trying to delete each and every object in separate API call (or group of objects) to delete all objects, which results in a lot of API calls and it takes time.

```
2022-03-14T23:20:35.729+0530 [INFO]  plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v3.67.0_x5: 2022/03/14 23:20:35 [INFO] Deleting S3 Bucket (<bucket-name>) Object (<object-name-x>) Version: null: timestamp=2022-03-14T23:20:35.729+0530

..
..

2022-03-14T23:20:35.729+0530 [INFO]  plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v3.67.0_x5: 2022/03/14 23:20:35 [INFO] Deleting S3 Bucket (<bucket-name>) Object (<object-name-y>) Version: null: timestamp=2022-03-14T23:20:35.729+0530
```

Don't tf have an easy way to call a single API call to the empty S3 bucket and then delete the S3 bucket during destroy?

Comment: Are you aware of an "empty S3 bucket" API? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_Operations_Amazon_Simple_Storage_Service.html

Comment: No, we don't have. When we try the empty option from the management console. It empties the bucket quickly. So was looking for such an option.

Comment: Checked the management console REST API, it is also getting LIST of objects and deleting one by one (in batch) behind the scene. But still it is much faster than tf emptying the bucket.

Comment: You could add a lifecycle policy that deletes files after 1 day, wait until files are gone then destroy. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59411240/empty-aws-s3-bucket-with-lifecyle

Comment: I am trying to delete tf workspace in PR so its lifecycle will be < 1 day in most of the cases. And don't want to delete files automatically before PR review, the reviewer may need to look at result files.